# find groups of neighboring True in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series with `True` and `False` and need to find all groups of `True`.
This means that I need to find the start index and end index of neighboring `True`values.

The following code gives the intended result but is very slow, inefficient and clumsy.

```
import pandas as pd

def groups(ser):
    g = []

    flag = False
    start = None
    for idx, s in ser.items():
        if flag and not s:
            g.append((start, idx-1))
            flag = False
        elif not flag and s:
            start = idx
            flag = True
    if flag:
        g.append((start, idx))
    return g

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ser = pd.Series([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=bool)
    print(ser)

    g = groups(ser)
    print("\ngroups of True:")
    for start, end in g:
        print("from {} until {}".format(start, end))
    pass
```

output is:

```
0      True
1      True
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6     False
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11    False
12     True
13    False
14     True

groups of True:
from 0 until 1
from 4 until 4
from 7 until 10
from 12 until 12
from 14 until 14
```

There are similar questions out there but non is looking to find the indices of the group starts/ends.

- [Label contiguous groups of True elements within a pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933657/label-contiguous-groups-of-true-elements-within-a-pandas-series)
- [Streaks of True or False in pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893702/streaks-of-true-or-false-in-pandas-series)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's common to use `cumsum` on the negation to check for consecutive blocks. For example:

```
for _,x in s[s].groupby((1-s).cumsum()):
    print(f'from {x.index[0]} to {x.index[-1]}')
```

Output:

```
from 0 to 1
from 4 to 4
from 7 to 10
from 12 to 12
from 14 to 14
```

Comment: Nice. Seems to work. I'm still struggling to understand how it works. `s[s]` returns you only the True values (in my case 9 items). Now you group it based on the cumulative sum of the negation of the original series (with 15 elements). How does `groupby` works in case you cast it on a series with 9 elements and pass it a series with 15 elements

Comment: Pandas will align the index of the group series to the series/dataframe to-be-grouped. If you pass numpy array to `groupby`, you would need equal length.

Comment: Thanks, it is clearly working thus I'll accept it - EDIT: got it now :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools`:

```
In [478]: from operator import itemgetter
     ...: from itertools import groupby

In [489]: a = ser[ser].index.tolist() # Create a list of indexes having `True` in `ser` 

In [498]: for k, g in groupby(enumerate(a), lambda ix : ix[0] - ix[1]):
     ...:     l = list(map(itemgetter(1), g))
     ...:     print(f'from {l[0]} to {l[-1]}')
     ...: 
from 0 to 1
from 4 to 4
from 7 to 10
from 12 to 12
from 14 to 14
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 but the other answer was slightly faster